# Is there a way to flush a POSIX socket?

Tags: c, sockets, posix

Is there a standard call for flushing the transmit side of a POSIX socket all the way through to the remote end or does this need to be implemented as part of the user level protocol? I looked around the usual headers but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For Unix-domain sockets, you can use `fflush()`, but I'm thinking you probably mean network sockets.  There isn't really a concept of flushing those.  The closest things are:

1. At the end of your session, calling `shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR)` to close out writes on the socket.
2. On TCP sockets, disabling the Nagle algorithm with sockopt `TCP_NODELAY`, which is generally a terrible idea that will not reliably do what you want, even if it seems to take care of it on initial investigation.

It's very likely that handling whatever issue is calling for a 'flush' at the user protocol level is going to be the right thing.

Comment: I don't see any reason why disabling the Nagle algorithm "is generally a terrible idea". If you know what it does, there are many application protocol situations where disabling Nagle is exactly what you want to do. I suspect you haven't had a situation where you really needed to do that or you don't understand what it really does. In other words, this feature is there for a reason and it can also be disabled for a very good reason.

Comment: I tried using TCP_NODELAY but i got the following error- ‘TCP_NODELAY’ was not declared in this scope. 

I used- setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int));

Comment: You'll need to `#include <linux/tcp.h>` or whatever include file provides `TCP_NODELAY` on your system (try `fgrep -r 'define TCP_NODELAY' /usr/include`).

Comment: @Tall Jeff: Often enough you only need to disable nagle because there is no flushing mechanism!

Comment: Nagle could have been a wonderful thing if there was a TCP flush. Since it can optimize it's buffer size to the current segment size. If you disable nagle you have a buffer of your own which is not synchronized to the segment size and so you will send half-filled packets over the network...

Comment: `fflush` has nothing to do with the issue even for unix domain sockets. It's only relevant if you've wrapped your socket with a `FILE` via `fdopen`...

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that there isn't a way to flush AND that Nagle disabling is discouraged.  I got rid of a 40ms latency sending a command to a server and getting the reply (reducing it to < 1ms) by disabling Nagle.  Still, I'm calling write() with 1-4 bytes at a time, so I imagine it could be even faster if I could explicitly tell when to flush, rather than waiting for some stupid timeout!

Comment: What I do is enable Nagle, write as many bytes (using non-blocking I/O) as I can to the socket (i.e. until I run out of bytes to send, or the send() call returns EWOULDBLOCK, whichever comes first), and then disable Nagle again.  This seems to work well (i.e. I get low latency AND full-size packets where possible)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: That is slick as hell.

Comment: In the go language, TCP_NODELAY is the default behavior. Did not see anyone complaining about it.

Comment: @TallJeff _there are many application protocol situations where disabling Nagle is exactly what you want to do_ Would you describe some of them please? Is there any common denominator?

Answer (score 34):

What about setting TCP_NODELAY and than reseting it back?
Probably it could be done just before sending important data, or when we are done with sending a message.

```
send(sock, "notimportant", ...);
send(sock, "notimportant", ...);
send(sock, "notimportant", ...);
int flag = 1; 
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int));
send(sock, "important data or end of the current message", ...);
flag = 0; 
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int));
```

As linux man pages says

> TCP_NODELAY ... setting this option forces an explicit flush of pending output ...

So probably it would be better to set it after the message, but am not sure how it works on other systems

Comment: This should work with linux at least; when you set TCP_NODELAY it flushes the current buffer, which should, according to the source comments, even flush when TCP_CORK is set.

Comment: I confirm that it works. I prefer to set and reset TCP_DELAY after sending the "important data or end of the current message" because it allow to put this stuff inside a flush socket method.

Comment: You describe a situation where "notimportant" messages are mixed with messages that are to be sent ASAP. For this situation, I guess your solution is a  good way to circumvent the delay that might by introduced by Nagle. However, if you do not send multiple messages but one compound message, you should send it with single `send()` call! It's because even with Nagle, the first package is sent immediately. Only subsequent ones are delayed, and they are delayed only until the server acknowledges or replies. So just pack "everything" into the first `send()`.

Comment: It is true, but in this case, we do not know how large is non important data, nor if there were any delays between single sends. The problem arise when data is send in one direction. For example I work as a proxy - I forward everything I get relay that network will send it optimum way so I do not care. But then comes an important packet, which I want to send as soon as possible. Which is what I understand as flushing.

Answer (score 14):

In RFC 1122 the name of the thing that you are looking for is "PUSH".
However, there does not seem to be a relevant TCP API implementation that implements "PUSH". Alas, no luck.

Some answers and comments deal with the Nagle algorithm. Most of them seem to assume that the Nagle algorithm delays each and *every* send.
This assumption is not correct. Nagle delays sending *only when at least one of the previous packets has not yet been acknowledged* (http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml).

To put it differently: TCP will send the *first* packet (of a row of packets) *immediately*. Only if the connection is slow and your computer does not get a timely acknowledgement, Nagle will delay sending *subsequent data* until either (whichever occurs first)

- a time-out is reached or
- the last unacknowledged packet is acknowledged or
- your send buffer is full or
- you disable Nagle or
- you shutdown the sending direction of your connection

A good mitigation is to avoid the business of *subsequent data* as far as possible. This means: If your application calls `send()` more than one time to transmit a single compound request, try to rewrite your application. Assemble the compound request in user space, then call `send()`. Once. This saves on context switches (much more expensive than most user-space operations), too.

Besides, when the send buffer contains enough data to fill the maximum size of a network packet, Nagle does not delay either. This means: If the last packet that you send is big enough to fill your send buffer, TCP will send your data as soon as possible, no matter what.

To sum it up: Nagle is not the brute-force approach to reducing packet fragmentation some might consider it to be. On the contrary: To me it seems to be a  useful, dynamic and effective approach to keep both a good response time and a good ratio between user data and header data. That being said, you should know how to handle it efficiently.

Answer (score 11):

There is no way that I am aware of in the standard TCP/IP socket interface to flush the data "all the way through to the remote end" and ensure it has actually been acknowledged.

Generally speaking, if your protocol has a need for "real-time" transfer of data, generally the best thing to do is to set the `setsockopt()` of `TCP_NODELAY`. This disables the Nagle algorithm in the protocol stack and write() or send() on the socket more directly maps to sends out onto the network....instead of implementing send hold offs waiting for more bytes to become available and using all the TCP level timers to decide when to send. NOTE: Turning off Nagle does not disable the TCP sliding window or anything, so it is always safe to do....but if you don't need the "real-time" properties, packet overhead can go up quite a bit.

Beyond that, if the normal TCP socket mechanisms don't fit your application, then generally you need to fall back to using UDP and building your own protocol features on the basic send/receive properties of UDP. This is very common when your protocol has special needs, but don't underestimate the complexity of doing this well and getting it all stable and functionally correct in all but relatively simple applications. As a starting point, a thorough study of TCP's design features will shed light on many of the issues that need to be considered.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [linux-specific way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67333214/823738) to do this on TCP sockets:

You don't force the tcp stack to "send out data immediately", but remember that you and kernel are sending data as fast as you can. You can slightly reduce the delay between `send` and actual delivery with `TCP_NODELAY`.

But basically, by doing `send` you've done your part and you just have to wait for tcp to do its part.

You can Use `ioctl` on the socket with `SIOCOUTQ` or `TIOCOUTQ` to query the status of delivery and just wait until it's finished. This should be be enough. Especially for use-cases like sending an application-level packet fragments.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be extremely difficult, if not impossible to implement correctly. What is the meaning of "flush" in this context? Bytes transmitted to network? Bytes acknowledged by receiver's TCP stack? Bytes passed on to receiver's user-mode app? Bytes completely processed by user-mode app?

Looks like you need to do it at the app level...

Comment: Nagle = don't send to wire immediately. No Nagle = send to wire immediately. The in-between option stares right in everyone's face: don't send to wire immediately (Nagle) except when I say to Send Now (the elusive TCP Flush).

Comment: @romkyns Nevertheless the actual send() is asynchronous w.r.t. the sending, regardless of the Nagle state.

Comment: @Roman Nagle does _not unconditionally_ equal _don't send to wire immediately_.

Answer (score 0):

TCP gives only best-effort delivery, so the act of having all the bytes leave Machine A is asynchronous with their all having been received at Machine B.  The TCP/IP protocol stack knows, of course, but I don't know of any way to interrogate the TCP stack to find out if everything sent has been acknowledged.

By far the easiest way to handle the question is **at the application level**.  Open a second TCP socket to act as a back channel and have the remote partner send you an acknowledgement that it has received the info you want.  It will cost double but will be completely portable and will save you hours of programming time.

Comment: I don't think you need a second socket....it would seem reasonable that the far end could send something back on the same socket, no?

Comment: It does not help you in reducing the send-delays that TCP (especially nagle) produces. But reducing send-delays would be one of the most interesting point in having a flush for TCP.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the tcp option SO_LINGER to set a certain timeout and then close the socket in order  to make sure all data has been sent (or detect failure to do so) upon the closeing of a connection. Other than that, TCP is a "best effort" protocol, and it doesn't provide any real guarantees that data will ever actually reach the destination (in contrast to what some seems to believe), it just tries it best to get it delivered in correct order and as soon as possible.

Answer (score -3):

Use fsync():

sock_fd is integer file descriptor from socket(..., ...) call

fsync(sock_fd);

Comment: This flushes files, not sockets.

Comment: Which must be why it works so well on UNIX Domain Sockets

Comment: Not for me, I'm getting `EINVAL`. (As verified by strace on a UDS I just wrote a bunch of bytes to.)