# Client-Server python : sending multiple messages at same time become grouped

Tags: python, client

I have a python client-server where one of the tasks is to send 10 messages in a row to the client. The problem is, the client receives only 1 message being the concatenation of the 10 messages sent. The code looks like this.

```
client:
while 1:
        msg = self.connection.recv(1024).decode()
        print (msg)

server:
for i in range (10):
    client.send(i.encode())
```

Client should receive, 0, then 1, then 2, then 3... but he doesn't. He gets 0123456789.

Is there a way to force unique sendings? Or do i have to code a parsing system ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4408018/391161

Comment: The client is waiting for `1024` bytes.

Answer (score -1):

you can reduce the number of bytes for `recv()`. That will do the trick.