# Socket programming for Python 2.7.10 with PyPy 5.1.2: Flush -- send data immediately

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server and many client implemented in Python, talking over sockets. I want message sent from both sides to be rushed immediately to the other side.

I found [this](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/790818-socket-flushing) article which talks about calling `.flush()` on the socket. However, I don't see any `flush()` api in the *python* doc [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407835/python-socket-flush) is a stackoverflow answer regarding the similar question.

- It suggests a naive option of closing the socket. However, I want to keep one connection and not re-connect again and again(to avoid complexity of code and useless burden on system.)
- It has another answer suggesting to convert the socket to a textfile like object and then call `flush` on it. However, comments there raise question on its credibility and it is for python 3 and is not accepted answer as well.

I do NOT necessarily need TCP socket, UDP is fine for me as well. But the only thing I want is that data should be sent immediately. Any suggestions for achieving that? I would prefer clean solution, however, hacks are welcome as well.

Comment: What library are you using? There should not be a need to flush data from a buffer.

Comment: You could try ZMQ or kafka from what I understand of your question.

Comment: @roganjosh I am using python's module socket(import socket). What do you mean by no need to flush data? My messages are of size 25 B or so. Won't TCP wait for certain fixed time to try to accumulate more data?

Comment: I actually have never used the base library for sockets. I have a hunch you would benefit from Zero MQ but it's hard to say