# Flush a socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, flush

Is there a way in python to flush a socket once a request has been sent and the information has been obtained correctly?

I have a socket that is used to send different commands at different times, so I was just wondering if this was possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general no is the answer - you can't flush a TCP socket.  All that is under the control of TCP.  Take a look at [this question for some more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855544/is-there-a-way-to-flush-a-posix-socket)