# UnpicklingError on data received from socket

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, pickle

**Context:**
I have a system with a `server.py` file and a `live_client.py`. Server is constantly updating an object. The system works correctly if I send the attributes of the object (which are numbers) via sockets (`cliend.send(str(obj.attribute_to_send).encode('utf-8')`).

**Problem:**
After, I tried to send the object from the server with pickle `client.send(pickle.loads(obj))`. Problem occured when the the client tries to get the object back with `pickle.loads(data_received)`. **Error code:** `_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated`.

**server.py**

```
async def stream_feed_clients():
    obj_gen = object_generator()
    global object
    global STREAM_CLIENTS
    async for obj in obj_gen:
        object = obj        
        for client in STREAM_CLIENTS: #STREAM_CLIENTS:Each time a client connects, another thread stores the client in this variable
            try:
                client.send(pickle.dumps(obj))
            except ConnectionResetError:
                client.close()
                print("Client disconnected!")
                STREAM_CLIENTS = set(filter(lambda x: x != client, STREAM_CLIENTS))
```

**client.py**

```
import socket, pickle, time

from CustomClass import MyClass

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = XXXX
try:
    c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    c.connect((HOST, PORT))
    message = {'client_type': 'LIVE'}
    print('Waiting')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Sending')
    c.send(pickle.dumps(message)) # NOTE: This pickle works. It is used to notify the server this is a client that wants live data.
    print('Message sent')
    while True:
        data = c.recv(4096 * 32) # I've been trying with different buffer sizes.
        obj = pickle.loads(data) # ERROR OCCURS HERE: _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
        print(obj.a)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Closing connection to server')
    c.close()
    print('Connection closed')
    print('Exiting...')
    exit()
```

**Class code of object being sent**

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    
    def get_a(self):
        return self.a
```

Comment: The client didn't receive the entire pickle in the first recv call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402731/socket-beginreceive-merging-tcp-packets or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663775/two-tcp-ip-socket-send-requests-were-actually-handled-in-one-tcp-message or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67726193/python-socket-recv-is-splitting-received-message or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641840/receiving-end-of-socket-splits-data-when-printed

Comment: Those are hardly the same question

Comment: They are all questions about the fact that one send doesn't equal one recv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704