# How to enable tcp psh flag in TCP/IP stack?

Tags: c, linux, tcp

How to enable the `TCP PSH` flag in write function to send the the message without filling the buffer?

Comment: What language are you programming in? You could add a tag with said language to your question, so people can find your question more easily.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on C language

Comment: check this thread out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855544/is-there-a-way-to-flush-a-posix-socket

Comment: Sometimes, it is nice to use UDP. It is bare-bones, but then you get much more control (and more work to do) in your application layer protocol. But of course, this may be impractical for your current work. Here is an interesting article: https://1024monkeys.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/game-servers-udp-vs-tcp/

Comment: Additional note is that there are system-dependent ways of checking for TCP ACK (for example, reading TCP_INFO in Linux), but that only tells you that the remote server has received the packets, not that the user application has read everything in the corresponding byte stream.

Comment: Setting the PSH flag is a waste of time. It doesn't make any difference at the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not seeing your packets going out without the PSH flag set now already? Some experimentation here showed that the following packet in tcpdump:

```
00:00:47.633884 IP 90.155.34.205.52092 > 216.58.222.100.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:16, ack 1, win 29, options [nop,nop,TS val 35956508 ecr 2650150746], length 15: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.0
E..CD.@.@...Z."..:.d.|.P......QM...........
.$.....ZGET / HTTP/1.0
```

went out using a very simple boring write() - from strace'ing netcat:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("216.58.222.100")}, 16) = 0
write(3, "GET / HTTP/1.0\n", 15)        = 15
```

It looks to me like the PSH flag is only unset on if for example I transmit more data than fits in a single segment, in which case only the last segment will have PSH, indicating there's more data coming up for now.